# How to properly call textfile in javaprogram on mac?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, path, text-files

In my assignment, a series of text files are needed in order for a picross game to occur that the user can play. While I have all the code properly set and done, when i try and path the folder within my assignment that contains all the textfiles for the game, it tells me that what've i provided is a string not path and won't accept my answer. Is there any other way I could input the textfiles on mac rather then through the pathname since it does not work?

[image: image of what ends up happening]

Comment: Don't screenshot text.  Paste the text in the question, formatted as code.  Build the project it will generate a compile error, you can post that as well, formatted as code.

Comment: That said, the compiler is telling you that the PicrossPuzzlePool constructor requires Path, so you must provide it a Path not a String.  Study to learn the basics of Java types and Programming.  Study a [Path tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) and the javadoc for the APIs you are using.  They tell you how to convert between strings and paths.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is referring to the `java.nio.file.Path` Interface, you can look at the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), along with the documentation for `java.nio.file.Paths` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)

I expect something like this should work:

```java
Path path = Paths.get("/your/path/here");
```